# Secret Information in Programs

Tags: java, password-protection, secret-key

So I read [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/205606/strategy-for-keeping-secret-info-such-as-api-keys-out-of-source-control) on Programmers SE and I got a little confused. In short, the solution is to keep all secret information in config files. Now this is where I'm confused. Couldn't a user just go searching for this file?

What methods are used to prevent users from finding the file? I'm using Java on Windows if that changes the answer at all.

I would think Encryption would come up but I'm not sure how that helps if the user can just decompile your source.

**EDIT**: To clarify further, my intention is to use API Keys (in this case 1, singular key) in an executable JAR file.

Comment: The question was about a developer developing an open source program, so that everyone was able to read the API secrets he needs to access some services. The solution was to not store the API secrets with the source code but let the forking developer get their own key and put it in their configuration. You're just confused. Your problem is a different one, namely that you need to give the user a secret that the user can't have. Classical paradox. There are solutions to this, but they depend on what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: @MarcusMüllerꕺꕺ At the moment, I'm just aiming to create a simple executable JAR file with Swing.

Comment: @Spedwards What's the secret information you (think you) need to store?

Comment: Then the original question applies -- your customer needs to get his own API Key and fill it in, *or* you need to set up some kind of proxy that your customer connects to. Also note that most modern auth schemes respect this problem by making a distinction between API keys and client keys

Comment: @Spedwards Does none of the answers answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

This depends what you are trying to achieve. I will assume here that the user has access to the enviroment in which your software is running. If you need to store some secret information, then you can use encryption, where the user has to supply a key. This is difficult to implement yourself correctly, but there are plenty of libraries and resources for this.

If your problem is exactly as described in the Programmers SE- you want to share code without sharing the 'secret' settings- extract the settings into a configuration file and don't share the configuration file. You can give a template, but with the secrets missing.

Answer (score 0):

Having read the link you provided I can think of the following below. Also please feel free to check the [Security network (one interesting question here)](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/38566).

---

For a example in a database config file you could have an entry like

```
<%= ENV['USER_NAME'] %>
<%= ENV['PASSWORD'] %>
```

and those two variables are environment variables that you set.

---

Using encryption would be similar. You'd store an encrypted/hashed key in a config file and you use that data to see if there is a match when needed.

- Encrypted data can be decrypted with a corresponding key
- Cryptographically hashed data is very hard to crack

You'd need to design that appropriately whatever your requirements are.

---

And you can combine both methods too if you wish.

---

### Example

I invite to have a look at my [GitHub project's config folder](https://github.com/Elyasin/Come-Malaka-Expenses/tree/master/config). In particular the yaml files. I use the first method above mostly. It is a RoR project.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really protect your informations if they are somehow available to the end-user - even if they are somehow crypted as long as your software is also available on the client. It only depends on the criminal energy the attacker will invest to get them.

One possibility could be to use ie. connection pooling for a database connect.

With this technique you get the connection object remote without the knowledge of the password - so you can use the connection within your app but the user cannot use informations to connect to the database with some sql tool.

See here for details: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_pool